# Webbrowser support after 2022 - Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an application in which System.Forms.WebBrowser is being used.
Since Internet Explorer will be retired and go out of support on June 2022, Will System.Forms.WebBrowser will be supported after 2022 or in the newer versions of windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft encourages customers to migrate to Microsoft Edge, because it provides support for legacy and modern websites and apps with [Edge IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality).

Internet Explorer mode in Microsoft Edge enables backward compatibility and will be supported through at least 2029. Additionally, Microsoft will provide notice one year prior to the retirement of IE mode.

So I think what we discussed after that is mainly about the issues in Edge IE mode rather than a specific control.

For more related Q & A, please refer to this official blog: [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).